# How to include third party library files to custom module without composer

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

I need to include Youtube API library files for my custom module.
Without composer, it should be done.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

**Option 1**: Magento 2 install extension using COMMAND LINE (Recommended)

Your Magento 2 extensions can be installed in a few minutes by going through these following steps

Step 1: Download/purchase the extension

Step 2: Unzip the file into a temporary directory

Step 3: Upload it to your Magento installation root directory

Step 4: Disable the cache under System­ >> Cache Management

Step 5: Enter the following at the command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I asked question about how to include libraries to my custom module.